# JMeter setting timestamp value after predefined amount of minutes

Tags: jmeter, request

We are using JMeter to test load for some simple html pages (GET requests for a total of ~1.5 hour). In order to test server ehcache mechanism (forcing cache store etc.), we are using a query param named **ts** in pages' request path as following:

**Path**: SERVER_NAME/page1?ts=${__time(Y-M-D-H-mm)}

This will create different requests per minute/hour/ etc - (of course different threads can use same timestamp value ts). As an example:

- ts=2022-3-89-21-36
- ts=2022-3-89-21-37
- ts=2022-3-89-21-38

Is it possible to allow timestamp value only after predefined amount of minutes? E.g. for previous example if we want 5 minutes:

- ts=2022-3-89-21-36
- ts=2022-3-89-21-41
- ts=2022-3-89-21-46

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of possible solutions would be pre-generating the timestamps and writing them into the CSV file somewhere in [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-setup-thread-group-jmeter-when-preparing-load-test/) using [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and the code like:

```
import groovy.time.TimeCategory

def now = new Date()
def numberOfLinesInCsv = 100

use(TimeCategory) {
    1.upto(numberOfLinesInCsv, {
        now = now + 5.minutes
        new File('ts.csv') << (now.format('Y-M-D-H-mm')) << System.getProperty('line.separator')
    })
}
```

Once done you can add [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) in the main Thread Group and configure it to read `ts.csv` file.